# Realm Object Server Resource Requirements

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am considering trying out the realm object server. Does anyone have real world experience with deploying it for production use that can comment on what level of resources are required? e.g. if I were to deploy to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Full Disclaimer: I work for Realm)*

The Realm Mobile Platform was only announced 3 months ago, so it might be a little while longer before production uses cases start to appear.

It's hard to say what your required resources would be because it obviously depends on your use case, including number of concurrent connections, the size of the data, and the rate of the data you're synchronizing.

If you're starting off, it would make sense to only commit to the minimum level of resource tiers that AWS provides and only extend it when you can see that you're bumping up against the limits.

Our one major recommendation is that wherever possible, you elect to use SSD storage instead of traditional hard drives to ensure the fastest read/write speeds on the server side.

In any case, with the Developer Edition of the Realm Mobile Platform being completely free to use, I encourage you to give it a try first-hand to see how it fits with your use case.